# Getting item from a function then concatenating in java

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to access an entry of map with a given hash code and then concatenate them into one long string forming a sentence however my Java knowledge is very poor and some of them are located inside of a function or even inside of a function of a function.
Can I get some guidance on how to do this thank you.

```
    public static void secondMessage() {
    aab();
    String Value1 = map.get(97);
    aba();
    cbc();
    cbb();
    String Value2 = map.get(3159);
    ccc();
    
}

public static void ccc() {
    bab();
    bcc();
}
public static void aba() {
    map.get(2301506);
}
public static void abb() {
    map.get(3540684);
}

public static void aab() {
    map.get(-1079530081);
    
}
public static void baa() {
    map.get(3139);
}
public static void bba() {
    map.get(98256);
}
public static void cbb() {
    map.get(3540684);
}
public static void bcc() {
    map.get(-103839003);
}
public static void cbc() {
    map.get(-309387644);
}
public static void bab() {
    abb();
    bba();
    baa();
}
```

}

Comment: If I understand correctly you are looking for reduction. Initial step you have an empty string, then you keep appending entries from the map to that string. If that is the case, you may also consider using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/buffers.html) instead of String. For now you can keep thing simple and stick with a String.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you need to do a lot of string concatenation it's usually better to use `StringBuilder` rather than concatenating a bunch of `Strings` for performance reasons. `StringBuffer` can also be used as well.

The intent of trying to get words out of the map is not clear. For example, the below method will get a word matching the key 3540684 but it won't do anything with it (no assignment happens).

```
public static void abb() {
    map.get(3540684);
}
```

If you insisted on making a method to return each specific word then the following would be a replacement.

```
public static String abb() {
    return map.get(3540684);
}
```

Here I assume `map` is of type `Map<Integer, String>` or an implementing class. Question doesn't explicitly mention the map definition.

Some possible solutions using `StringBuilder` are demonstrated below.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
        map.put(66, "Chicken");
        map.put(12312, "I");
        map.put(432341, "hello");
        map.put(834523, "am");
        map.put(32451, "Rooster");
        map.put(683, "a");

        // A method
        var sentence1 = new StringBuilder();
        addWord(sentence1, 432341, map);
        addWord(sentence1, 12312, map);
        addWord(sentence1, 834523, map);
        addWord(sentence1, 683, map);
        addWord(sentence1, 66, map);

        System.out.println(sentence1.toString());

        // Another way
        var sentence2 = generateSentence(map, new int[]{ 432341, 12312, 834523, 683, 66 } );

        System.out.println(sentence2);
    }

    public static void addWord(StringBuilder sb, int hashCode, HashMap<Integer, String> map) {
        sb.append(map.get(hashCode));
        sb.append("");
    }

    public static String generateSentence(HashMap<Integer, String> map, int[] hashCodes) {
        var sentence = new StringBuilder();

        for (var hashCode : hashCodes) {
            sentence.append(map.get(hashCode));
            sentence.append("");
        }

        return sentence.toString();
    }
```

Comment: `StringBuilder` vs `StringBuffer` explanation are out of scope for this question.

Comment: how would i go about accessing then returning for

public static void ccc() {
    bab();
    bcc();
} when i use return i get unreachable code error

Comment: If you want to make a parameter-less method/function, as in your methods, you would have to have the map defined as a property in a broader scope to be accessible. In my example, the map is only accessible in the body of `public static void main(String[] args)`.
You can move outside the curly brackets into the class scope and make a static map instead. `static HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>()` . You can read more about [variable scope here](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_scope.asp)

Comment: It is better to go through a structured java fundamentals tutorial or course that explain this stuff. These concepts are important for helping you to get started learning coding with Java.

Answer (score 0):

not void should change to String,try to use StringBuilder to contact Strings.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).